# Font Awesome and i3bar

Tags: linux, unicode, fonts, font-awesome

I want to add fontawesome icons to my i3bar. I installed the package "ttf-font-awesome" via yaourt and added the necessary unicode characters to my i3status config and added the font pango as "FontAwesome" to my i3bar config. The icons should be displaying but all that shows are the unicode characters. Is there a specific package I need to install or did I edit the configs improperly?

Comment: Better ask on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 26):

Funny thing is that i came over this thread while searching for the same.
Anyways, according to [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/I3#Iconic_fonts_in_the_status_bar) you load FontAwesome like this `font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono, FontAwesome 8`, and the icons according to the [cheatsheet](https://fontawesome.com/v5/cheatsheet). For example `&#xf120;` for the terminal icon.

edit: as mentioned below, you copy/paste the icon itself from the cheatsheet.
I recommend you try out either one, and stick with the one that is working.

Mini example below.

```
# set $ws2  "2:&#xf120;"  # With the icon code from the cheasheet
set $ws2 "1 "           # With the icon copy/pasted from the cheatsheet

bar {
    ...
    font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono, FontAwesome 8
    ...
}
```

Comment: Worked for me after adding the font directive in `bar { ... }`, but for `set $ws2 ...` I had to copy and paste the icon, using the icon code didn't work (it just interpreted the code literally)

Comment: Same here, had to go to http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/ and copy/paste icons. However, according to archWiki, vim and emacs let you type those characters with a shortcut :
- in Emacs: ctrl+x, 8, Enter, f004 (the icon unicode), Enter
- in Vim (while in insert mode): Ctrl+v, uf004 (the icon unicode)

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, I had to use "FontAwesome" for the family name: `font pango:DejaVu Sans Mono, FontAwesome 8`

Comment: I guess @frabjous' comment should be included in the answer as well. `Awesome` didn't work for me but `FontAwesome` did.

Comment: I'm not using Arch Linux and I3 myself anymore. So I can't really verify if the names has changed, but I did update the answer to what seems to be correct. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 6):

Change in your `bar {`:

```
font pango:monospace 8, FontAwesome 8
```